# Dúvida com funções em C

Tags: c, funções

Como eu faço para que a variável que eu usei para armazenar valor que eu li no scanf, seja passada para a função que eu criei?

Ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
}

int soma(int a, b){
    int soma;
    soma= a+b;
    return soma;
}
```

Comment: Não é só colocar depois do `scanf` a chamada para a função? Algo como `int resultado = soma(a, b);`

Comment: @hkotsubo exato, salvo o problema dele ser outro.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(int a, int b); // prototipo da função

int main()
{
  int a, b, resultado;
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  resultado = soma(a, b); // chamei a função e estou passando para variavel resultado
  printf("%d\n", resultado);
}

int soma(int a, int b)  // Quando voce for fazer uma função cada variavel deve ter seu tipo
{
  int soma;
  soma = a + b;
  return soma;
}
```